# How to set custom connection timeout for all requests to a certain backend?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, mod-rewrite

I am looking for something like:

```
<Proxy balancer://myset>
BalancerMember http://www.example.com:8080 timeout=1
</Proxy>
```

But I don't want to specify what urls go to that backend at all --- this is controlled else where --- like RewriteCond on certain ENV being set.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set options for a particular proxy connection with the `ProxySet` directive. It looks like you created the balancer group just to try to set the timout, so, depending on the rest of your configuration, something like:

```
ProxySet http://www.example.com:8080 timeout=1
```

Comment: Thanks very much that's exactly what I am looking for!!!